# How can I get image download url from firebase storage file, if I know what name it will be stored under?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-storage

I have a firebase resize images extension that once the image uploaded to a specific folders(profilePhotos in my case) it converts that image to smaller size(320x320 in my case) and just adds **"_320x320"** to the end of the name.

Initially, I had a cloud function creating urls and updating the correlating document in firestore via **getSignedUrl()** until I realised that all signed urls expire after 7 days.

This is how I get the original pictures download url from the front end:

```
              uploadTask.on(
                "state_changed",
                (snapshot) => {
                  const progress =
                    (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
                  setProgress(progress);
                },
                (error) => {
                  console.log("error" + error);
                },
                () => {
                  getDownloadURL(userUploadRef).then(async (downloadUrl) => {
                    // code that updates the document in firestore by adding the url
```

If I know that the only difference between the original and resized image name is that one ends with **_320x320**, can I just alter the download url to get the download url of my image, if so how can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

Changing the download URL would only work if the access token is passed on from the original image to the resized image, which I'm not sure if it is (the Extension supported that at some point, but I recall there were issues with it).

The better approach would be to determine the download URL for the resized image name by a separate call to `getDownloadURL` with a reference to the correct path:

```
const storage = getStorage();
const resizedRef = ref(storage, 'images/stars_320x320.jpg');
getDownloadURL(resizedRef).then(...
```

Comment: wouldn't that just fail, because the resized image would not exist yet, as it would take 1, 5 or 20 seconds for the newly resized image to be ready?

Comment: If it runs before the resized image is created yet. I didn't realize you wanted to do this as part of the resize flow. In that case, you might want to have a look at "Extensions events" that were just announced at I/O: https://firebase.blog/posts/2022/05/whats-new-at-google-io and https://invertase.io/blog/introducing-extension-events.